# How to deploy a smartcontract in EOS on testnet using SET after creating abi and wsm files?

Tags: smartcontracts, eos

```
aditib@WJLP-1098:~/contracts$ cleos -u https://jungle.eosio.cr:443 set contract adtester1234 hello/ -p adtester1234@active

Failed to get existing code hash, continue without duplicate check...
Reading WASM from /home/aditib/contracts/hello/hello.wasm...
Publishing contract...
Error 3090003: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations
Ensure that you have the related private keys inside your wallet and your wallet is unlocked.
Error Details:
transaction declares authority '{"actor":"adtester1234","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it.
```

**I made an account on jungle testnet by the name adtester1234.It is showing on the explorer,I checked.**

**Also, the wallet is unlocked and do contain requires public and private keys for the account.**

```
aditib@WJLP-1098:~/contracts$ cleos wallet private_keys -n jungle-wallet-2 --password PW5K1SUrrGcraekXgBQN3137qfkqSyFrVVRdkxWgzpaZnJLMYPg4n
[[
    "EOS5HWzxBoDTGj2hMeA9WGphVCbXmcxB78QCTWgPybyCUvNnyVznH",
    "5JBGrBZBhQ2Zjqbj4z8dKyu9fvwowg4sdqZ5vbkM9kSNVJrH7Db"
  ]
]
```

**I tried adding sign transaction:**

```
aditib@WJLP-1098:~/contracts$ cleos -u https://jungle.eosio.cr:443 set contract adtester1234 hello/ -p adtester1234@active -s

Failed to get existing code hash, continue without duplicate check...
Reading WASM from /home/aditib/contracts/hello/hello.wasm...
Publishing contract...
Failed to connect to nodeos at https://jungle.eosio.cr:443; is nodeos running?
```

**Should nodeos be running if I'm connecting to a testnet endpoint?**

I'm using UBUNTU 18.04 LTS on Windows. I refered to similar questions on stackoverflow but it didn't work for me. I hope someone can guide me.

*Why is this error occuring? How to solve it? Why I'm I unable to fetch the codehash?
Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Are you sure that ```https://jungle.eosio.cr:443``` API Endpoint is up and working ?
Maybe try with this ```https://jungle.eosn.io:443/```

Comment: I tried other endpoints too, same error.

Comment: But this endpoint is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint I have used is not working.

Here is a list of working endpoints which I tried and are working:

- https://api.jungle.alohaeos.com:443
- https://jungle2.cryptolions.io:443
- https://jungle.eosn.io:443
- http://jungle2.cryptolions.io:80